# Passing an image through as webservice

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, web-services, webservice-client

how would I go about passing an image from an ASMX webservice, through to my silverlight front end? I am using .Net 4.0 and Silverlight 4 front end, and SQLServer 2008 to store the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try passing the image as a base64 string directly out of the database and decode it on the front end once it's received from the web service.